# How to add annotations on a classes properties, and iterate on properties?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I want to add annotations on my classes properties, and then iterate all my properties with the ability to lookup the annotations also.

So for example, I have a class like:

```
public class User {

   @Annotation1
   private int id;
   @Annotation2
   private String name;
   private int age;

   // getters and setters
}
```

Now I want to be able to loop through my properties, and be able to know what annotation (if any) is on the property.

I want to know how to do this using just java, but also curious if using either spring, guava or google guice would make this any easier (if they have any helpers to do this easier).

Comment: Cute how you've been a member 3 1/2 years, asked 1,779 questions and still don't format your code.

Comment: What have you tried? (read annotation-related java standard APIDocs, google for examples of custom annotations etc )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that utilizes the (barely maintained) bean instrospection framework. It's an all Java solution that you can extend to fit your needs.

```
public class BeanProcessor {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         final Class<?> beanClazz = BBean.class;
         BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClazz);
         PropertyDescriptor[] propertyInfo = info.getPropertyDescriptors();
         for (final PropertyDescriptor descriptor : propertyInfo) {
            try {
               final Field field = beanClazz.getDeclaredField(descriptor
                     .getName());
               System.out.println(field);
               for (final Annotation annotation : field
                     .getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
                  System.out.println("Annotation: " + annotation);
               }

            } catch (final NoSuchFieldException nsfe) {
               // ignore these
            }
         }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: curious, do any of the libs I mentioned help with this? like spring or guava or guice? i.e. find all annotations helpers or something?

Comment: Guava? Doubtful. Spring/Guice maybe though I haven't seen a class in either framework that fulfills what you described in your question. You might want to check out [Google Reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections).

Answer (score 3):

Below is the way to create your own annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

public @interface Annotation1 {
    public String name();
    public String value();
}
```

After defining your annotation, use the annotation as you mentioned in your question and you can use the below reflection method to get the annotated class details

```
Class aClass = User.class;
Annotation[] annotations = aClass.getAnnotations();

for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof Annotation1){
        Annotation1 myAnnotation = (Annotation1) annotation;
        System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
        System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the method below which creates a stream of all fields in a class and it's superclasses which have a specific annotation.
There are other ways to do it. But I think this solution is very easy to reuse and practical because when you need to know those fields, it is usually to do an action on each field. And a Stream is exactly what you need to do that.

```
    public static Stream<Field> getAnnotatedFieldStream(Class<?> theClass, Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType) {
      Class<?> classOrSuperClass = theClass;
      Stream<Field> stream = Stream.empty();
      while(classOrSuperClass != Object.class) {
        stream = Stream.concat(stream, Stream.of(classOrSuperClass.getDeclaredFields()));
        classOrSuperClass = classOrSuperClass.getSuperclass();
      }
      return stream.filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(annotationType));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you would use reflection to get the fields of the class and then call something like `getAnnotations()` on each field.